# Receiving an error from eclipse when reading a text file

Tags: java, eclipse

This is the problem code: if I import the text file at the project level, it gives me this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at edu.ilstu.ConcertDriver.main(ConcertDriver.java:59)
```

If I only import the file to a lower directory such as the source folder, it throws the FileNotFoundException. What am I doing wrong?

---

My file contains the following elements:

Maroon 5
15
40
One Direction
10
50
Pearl Jam
20
30

note that after 30, it returns to the next line

---

```
String inputFileName = "concerts.txt";
Scanner inputStream = null;
try
{
    inputStream = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName));
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
    System.out.println("Error opening the file " + inputFileName);
    System.exit(0);
}


String bandName1=null;
int showCapacity1=0;
int ticketPrice1=0;
String bandName2=null;
int showCapacity2=0;
int ticketPrice2=0;
String bandName3=null;
int showCapacity3=0;
int ticketPrice3=0;

bandName1 = inputStream.nextLine();
showCapacity1 = inputStream.nextInt();
ticketPrice1 = inputStream.nextInt();
bandName2 = inputStream.nextLine();
showCapacity2 = inputStream.nextInt();
ticketPrice2 = inputStream.nextInt();
bandName3 = inputStream.nextLine();
showCapacity3 = inputStream.nextInt();
ticketPrice3 = inputStream.nextInt();
```

Comment: What's in your file? Edit your question with its content.

Comment: when you put in the project file, it means you have error in your code. when you move it, it means the file is not in the correct location. Let us see your file. A snippet

Comment: I added what is in the file (with placeholders)

Comment: Is there any empty space at the top of the file?

Comment: No. Maroon 5 is the first thing.

Comment: Which one is line 59? In other words, which line is causing the error?

Comment: Try adding inputStream.hasNextLine() and inputStream.hasNextInt() to check if there is something to scan.

Comment: So upon testing your program, I found that the second inputStream.nextLine() returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put the file in the project directory, it means you have error in your code (but file is in *correct* location - if you don't get `FileNotFOundException`). When you move the file, it means the file is not in the correct location.

For each Integer line, try and take each line an parse it

```
showCapacity1 = Integer.parseInt(inputStream.nextLine().trim());
```

Comment: I'm in a Java class for this and we haven't learned about parsing... There must be an easier way

Comment: try doing this first. if it works, then I'm assuming I know the problem. And let me know what happens. If it works I'll try and offer another solution.

Comment: Does it have something to do with the use of nextLine?

Comment: Let me ask you this. Is there any line space in between each line? And is there any empty lines at the top?

Comment: There is not at the top, and there are no spaces after each line. The only related thing is at the end when it moves the cursor to the 10th line after "30"

Comment: Yea that doesn't matter. It's recommended to read line by line to avoid this error. Sometimes the line will not automatically read to the next line when calling a `nextXXX()` that is not `nextLine()`. Even when trying to read words from each line, you should use `nextLine()` then parse (`split()`) the line.

Comment: I'm seeing what you mean, but I'm confused about this parsing business.

Comment: I see the issue, after it reads an int it's not advancing the line.

Comment: All parsing is doing is taking a `String` and turning it into its `Integer` value.  You can `parseDouble` and `parseFLoat()`. So what I'm doing, is taking the entire `nextLine` and `trim()`ing it, so there is no whitespace to the left or right, then taking that String value and turning it into an integer. This will only work if the String value is actually an Integer.  Also, note that when you read `nextLine()`, you always get a `String`, that's why we had to parse it. If this answer solved your problem, please accept answer.

Comment: So, because this is a text file, the "numbers" are actually strings?

Comment: No, I meant when you use `nextLine()` it returns a String, and you have to parse it to get in `int`. The numbers aren't `String`s, they can be read as numbers.

Comment: So I must read the integers as strings and then parse them? or is there a way to advance the line after nextInt()?

Comment: Try and use `inpuStream.tnextLine()` after each `nextInt()`. Not sure if it'll work, but you can try it. Just put it like that by itself without making it equal to anything.

Answer (score 2):

Input mismatch exception means that you are trying to get the wrong data type. I'm guessing your input file is the culprit, but you should add it here to make sure.

Comment: I've added it, I was thinking the same thing but I wasn't sure how to fix it.